# add outlook 2003 default signature to email

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook

have used the following JavaScript code, to create outlook 2003 emails from a web page.  The default signature is not showing up, but everything else works. How can I add the default signature?

Thanks in advance!

```
var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');
mailItem.To = document.getElementById("pEmail").value;
mailItem.CC ="test@tt.com";
mailItem.HTMLBody  = "Hello,";
mailItem.HTMLBody += "<p><hr></p>";
mailItem.display (0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer I was looking for, with the guidance of Dmitry Streblechenko. Thank you again Dmitry Streblechenko.  to add the signature to my script just add the following

```
 // add this before creating the actual email.
 var insp = mailItem.GetInspector;
 var mySigline = mailItem.HTMLBody;

 // build the actual email.

// Last line of email
 mailItem.HTMLBody += mySigline;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you wipe out the existing body when you set the HTMLBody property - you must merge the existing data. Also avoid using "+=" when working with HTMLBody.

Secondly, the signature is added when you call MailItem.Display or access MailItem.GetINspector. You must do that before you manipulate the body.

Comment: How would I merge them? can you provide examples

Comment: Search for the "<body" substring, find the next ">" (this is required if you have any attributes on the body element set), insert your text right after that ">".

Comment: Thank you very  much, but can you treat me like i am a newbie (which i am), thats why i asked for an example.  I dont know the lang but i can fudge my way around.  can you put the code i need to use in here please?

Comment: I don't use JavaScript, sorry.